# Wrong time recognition in creating post

Tags: php, date, time, wordpress

I'm using wordpress plugin [eventpost](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-post/) and when I want to create new post with a date of event for example: from: 22.1.2015 22:00 to: 23.1.2015 04:00, "to" date changes immediately to same date as "from". I found format of a date in database without leading zeros, could be this problem?

I tried manually change a date in database, but it returns error, maybe I did it wrong.

I set a date format in event post as Y/m/d H:i and l j F Y H:i UTC+1 in general. Any change probably doesn't any effect.
When I debug in browser I can't find, where is a var working with my date.

This problem cause wrong ordering when getting by custom query from database.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Picture on left side is expected time before click.
Picture on right side is when I click on that time - wrong.

[image: expected date]

Code, where I seek is in folder on site (download) I wroted earlier, but I didn'n know what to find or what to fix.

Comment: Not sure about your problem.

Comment: Please include in your post the input, the desired result, and the actual result.  Also include the code with which you are seeking assistance.

Comment: I edited the post. Does anyone has an idea what can cause that problem?